# How to conditionally load different routes based off device?

Tags: angular

**I need to load one of two route objects, depending on the device the user is using to login to our application.** Depending on which device the user entered, we will assign these or other paths to the `forRoot()` method.

Below is the code I've used in an attempt to solve this problem:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core' ;
import {Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '@guards';
import { DetectedDeviceService } from './core/services/detected-device.service';

const currentDevice  =  new DetectedDeviceService().detectIphone();
const routes: Routes =
 [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'main',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then((m)  => m.LoginModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/main/main.module').then((m)  => m.MainModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

const routesMobile: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'main',
      pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
      path: 'login',
      loadChildren: () => import('./pages/MobilePages/pages/login-mobile/login-mobile.module').then((m)  => m.LoginMobileModule),

  },
  {
      path: 'main',
      loadChildren: () => import('./pages/MobilePages/pages/main-mobile/main-mobile.module').then((m)  => m.MainMobileModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(currentDevice === 'mobile' ? routesMobile : routes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This does not work and causes an error, tell me if there is any other solution to this problem.

Comment: You say you are getting an error? Would you please share the error you're getting? This is an interesting question.

Comment: Yes, please provide error and plunker or something if possible - I'm interested as well...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plunker with basically the code you have working as expected (links are broken on the screen because "desktopRoutes" was used...

I'd bet something else is your problem - would need more info.

Plunk showing that check showRoot() working as expected:
https://embed.plnkr.co/L6ru7HUYpSMjB8RyozvE/

Comment: I hardcoded the device type since the angular plunker didn't have the dependency for it. Maybe getting that value (or not checking it) is your problem...